# Uploading Photo/Video to Instagram from Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, instagram

I want to allow the users of my Windows Phone 8.1 app, to share their Edited or Trimmed video to Instagram.

I think there isn't any Client Library of Instagram for Windows Phone. I come across this link:

- http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

But there is no way to upload Photo/Video to Instagram server.

Can someone guide me or redirect me to any useful link or sample code..? Any kind of help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can integrate with other app that already does this. 6tag is an app that allow other apps to send it parameters to share to Instagram. The problem after you start the share the app is opened it the user needs to understand.